# Allow a class to be casted as another class in Java

Tags: java

I have a very simple class, say

```
public class myInt {
    private Integer myint; // public?

    public myInt(Integer i) {
        this.myint = i;
    }

    public Integer getmyInt() {
        return myint;
    }
}
```

Now I need to use some functions that take as argument `ArrayList<Integer>`. Is it somehow possible to make my class *castable* as Integer?

Comment: Why not use `ArrayList<myInt>`?  Language here: `"primitive"` has a special meaning in Java, referring to certain base types in the language (`int`, `short`, `long`, etc.).

Comment: No. That is not possible. What is the problem exactly? Why can't you pass a List of Integers?

Comment: Since your class is not an integer or subset of integer it would not be possible.

Comment: Does someone mind to give a "regular" answer, so I can close the topic? I guess the question was answered.

Comment: @user3437460 No that is not possible. `Integer` is final.

Comment: @AndreasFester Ah, then it is not possible then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, when you say "primitive type" you refer specifically to certain types of variable (e.g. `int`, `char`), so in this case, if you want a literal answer, then the answer is "no", you can't cast `myInt` to `Integer` (btw, `Integer` is not a primitive type, whereas `int` is)

However if you want to achieve what you state you can create an empty `ArrayList<Integer>` and then query each of your `myInt` objects and call `myInt.getmyInt()` (since that returns an Integer) and add them to your `ArrayList<Integer>`.

For example, something like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myNumbersArray= new ArrayList<>(); 
myInt myNumber = new myInt(4);
myNumbers.add(myNumber.getmyInt());
```

Although I'm not sure why would you need to do this since you are basically taking an integer, wrapping it in a different object and then unwrapping it, so you could as well avoid the middle step, unless you are for some other reason using that middle construct.

Comment: I never say *primitive type*. How would that query look like?

Comment: You said "primitive class" which in the Java context could be confusing

Comment: Ok, I understand now that you where referring to a very simple class, in terms of complexity. Sorry for the confusion, but like I said in Java it's very common to refer to a primitive type as a primitive, so my wiring got confused :)

Answer (score -3):

If the cast needs to be supported there should be a relation(super/child) between the classes.Even with the same there can be run time errors while casting.

this will be a useful link

http://www.wideskills.com/java-tutorial/java-object-typecasting

Comment: Unfortunately, [Integer is a final class][1] so you can't actually extend it.

  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: you are absolutely right , I typed that by a very big mistake .